# how to make 2 lines in a text box in microsoft access 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I Have  Text Box With A Total Of My Address Book "address" & "city" & "State" & "Zip" But I Need A New Line Befor CITY

Comment: This is not clear. If you need more than one line in the text box, select multiline=True. If you need it to be taller to go from 3 to 4 lines, stretch it in the form designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you're using VBA or a query to build your address, the constant: `vbCrLf` will give you a new line.
- If you're typing into a textbox, then it's either **Enter** or **Ctrl-Enter**, depending on the property 'Enter Key Behavour' (on the 'Other' tab) to enter a new line.
- If you're trying to use the property of a textbox, such as **Control Source** or **Default**, then you need to use `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`

Comment: It look like you understand my question but where do i put the code?

Comment: Are you using VBA, a query, or a textbox? It's slightly different for each method.

Comment: If you're using e textbox, then you can't use the vb constants. Instead, use Chr(13) & Chr(10) for the new line. So on the textbox control source, enter (without the quotes): "=[field1] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [field2]". You can do multiple lines by adding Chr(13) & Chr(10) inbetween each field.

Comment: thanx a million for the great help it works wonderful my good is =[titel] & " " & [first] & " " & [last] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & [address] & " " & [streetname] & " " & [apt] & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & " " & [city] & " " & [state] & " " & [zip] so thanx again

Comment: i just want to understand what the code means 10 and 13 and why do you say to make 13 before 10

Comment: All characters have a code that represents them. Even invisible characters. The code group in VB is called ASCII. For example: 'A' is code 65, while 'a' is code 97. You can call up the character by using the function Chr(). In your case, you're using 13, which is a carriage return, and 10, which is a line feed. These two together gives you a new line. If you want to see some of the other codes, go to http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: vb.net and even VBA has a built in constant you can use for a new line. "vbCRlf" can thus be used in place of the chr(13) code posted here. And as noted if the user is entering data into the text box, then enter or ctrl-enter will start a new line when entering data into the text box.